# HTML redirect without opening new tab

Tags: html, redirect

I have the following code which redirects to a random webpage although it does so by opening a new tab which is often blocked by web browsers. Can this be amended to open the new site in the same tab?

Thanks in advance

```
<script>
var links = [ "google.com",
         "youtube.com",
         "reddit.com",
         "apple.com"]

var time = 3000;

var openSite = function() {

var randIdx = Math.random() * links.length;

randIdx = parseInt(randIdx, 10);

var link = 'https://www.' + links[randIdx];
return link;
};


setTimeout(function(){
    open(openSite())
     }, time);
</script>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrdT8.png)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```js
window.location.href = openSite();
```

Comment: Thanks for that, where would i add that in the code?

Comment: inside the timeout function instead of: open(openSite())